# Hamming distance

Tags: networking, hamming-distance

I'm reading the book of Computer networks by Andrew S. Tanenbaum. I'm confused about the hamming distance in this paragraph. Why does it say the Hamming distance is 3 in this construction? Thanks.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You are confusing between the figure and the written part.They are 2 different examples.In the diagram example of (11,7) Hamming code is given,while the example above it is discussing about (11,29).

> The Hamming distance between two strings of equal length is the number
>   of positions at which the corresponding symbols are different.

Hamming distance of (11,29) will be 3 as 11=01011 and 29=11101
Reach out if you want something else.
Cheers